# Image from StorageReference Firebase-Android

Tags: android, firebase, reference, storage, firebase-storage

```
     TextView myUsername=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.user);
    myProfile=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);
    Bundle bundleObject=getIntent().getExtras();
    myAccount=(Account) bundleObject.getSerializable("account");

    myUsername.setText(myAccount.get_username());

    StorageReference profile =
    FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
    .getReference().child("profiles").child(myAccount.getUID()).child("profile");

    profile.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(Profile.this, new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            myProfile.setImageURI(uri);
        }
    });
```

I'm trying to put the image from the Firebase Storage in the ImageView but is not showing and I don't have any error . What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ImageView` doesn't load images from the internet itself - and the URL retrieved from Storage is a regular HTTPS one. The `setImageURI` method is for loading from the local file system.

You can use a library like Glide or Picasso to do the image loading - if you take a look at FirebaseUI, you'll find a helpful integration that includes caching: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/storage

Comment: Glide.with(this).load(storageReference).into(imageView)?

Comment: Thank you!  It works.                  Glide.with(this).using(new FirebaseImageLoader()).load(storageRef).into(imageView)